# Looking for a Horrible-by-design chess engine

Tags: engines, software, arena

I am looking for a really-bad-by-design chess engine, compatible with Arena chess GUI. Not just lowering engine power..
I have tried lowering Stockfish's power, and it didn't suit my needs, so I am looking for a weak one!

Comment: Why? So you can beat it on occasion, or for some other purpose?

Comment: I am actually going to be using it to develop my own chess engine... I will have mine play it several thousand times, and it will learn common tactical mistakes and patterns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a whole list at http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/4040/

If you're looking for a weak engine, I'd suggest:

1. Predateur 2.2 64-bit
2. MicroMax
3. CupCake
4. BikJump

I know those four engines work and run smoothly, although they're quite weak (which is exactly what you want!). Any Elo 2000 rated human player can trash them easily.

__ **My Recommendation** __

If your engine can't even beat the lowest Stockfish level, maybe it'd be a better idea to focus on your engine, such as adding easy technqiues like null-move pruning. As an average human player, I can consistently beat the lowest Stockfish level, it plays around 1500-1600 level. Even the engines I mentioned might be too strong for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found it! [UFIM](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Ufim) works well for my purpose!